# Long title in table of content doesn't break properly

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking

My table of contents doesn't seem to be handling well titles which are just a little bit too long. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

As you can see some lines are breaking, but some (like the title of section 9.15) are not.

Here is the class and packages I use for the document.

```
\documentclass[paper=A5, fontsize=8pt, DIV=calc, pagesize=auto, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[subsectionbib]{bibunits}
\usepackage[left= 7.5em, right= 7.5em, bottom=13em]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex,hyperref]{xcolor} % pdf color support
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
   urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
   linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
   citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
 } 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents   


\chapter{some long title which is just a little bit too long}

\end{document}
```

After adding the lines

```
  \makeatletter
    \def\@pnumwidth{2em}
  \makeatother
```

as suggested by Gustavo, this is the result:

[image]

EDIT: Before using the package tocstyle, notice the lack of space after section number 10.10. At this point, all titles are breaking correctly.

[image]

Comment: Your MWE contains a couple of typos (`\tableofcontent` -- final `s` missing, and no backslash before `end{document}`).  Never mind :-).  But besides that, I'm not able to reproduce the behavior you are complaining about: if I increase the length of «some long title etc.» in tiny steps, it shrinks without overlapping the page number as long as it fits in a single line, and is correctly broken when it no longer fits.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I've had a second look at the problem modifying the MWE so that is reproduces the situation more closely and I think this a very happy coincidence in which the section name length is exactly the length available for it in the line so Latex fits it right there producing the output which is odd but correct. I am going to upvote Gustavo's answer as I think the `\@pnumwidth` change provides a nice output.

Comment: @jasikevicius23: “A very [_un_]happy coincidence”, I would say! :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** *This answer has been thoroughly edited (by its original author) in order to straighten it.*

As it happens, the way in which the standard *book* class, or the LaTeX kernel, implement the `\l@chapter` command, or, respectively, the `\@dottedtocline` command, makes it possible that such unfortunate line breaks may occasionally occur in the table of contents (or in similar tables, like the list of figures).  The problem is not apparent unless the width of the referred-to page number is wide enough.

To clarify the source of the problem, consider first the following simple example, in which the standard *book* class is used (but the same discussion applies to other classes as well, including *scrbook*):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left= 7.5em, right= 7.5em, bottom=13em]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
   urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
   linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
   citecolor    = red   %Colour of citations
}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{333}

\chapter{Quality of Service Optimization in Self-adapti\-ve}

Blah blah.

\chapter{Quality of Service Optimization in Self-adapti}

Foo bar.

\section{I should be sleeping now\ldots}
\ldots and not trying to post silly answer to \TeX.SX when I~am evidently too 
tired to reason correctly!


\section{I'll go}
Good night to everybody.

\section[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit enim ut fugiat]
Some text.

\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:
[image: Original version]

Compare it with the output produced by the following possible patch (which again, is suitable for the standard `book` class):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left= 7.5em, right= 7.5em, bottom=13em]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
   urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
   linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
   citecolor    = red   %Colour of citations
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hskip .5em \@plus 1fil % <<< MODIFICATION <<<
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{333}

\chapter{Quality of Service Optimization in Self-adapti\-ve}

Blah blah.

\chapter{Quality of Service Optimization in Self-adapti}

Foo bar.

\section{I should be sleeping now\ldots}
\ldots and not trying to post silly answer to \TeX.SX when I~am evidently too 
tired to reason correctly!


\section{I'll go}
Good night to everybody.

\section[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit enim ut fugiat]
Some text.

\end{document}
```

Here it is:
[image: First (pretty pointless) patch]

As you see, the additional `.5em` of space inserted between the text of the entry and the page number forces the desired line break.

Of course, this patch is pretty pointless, since it is much simpler, and more general, to adjust `\@pnumwidth`, as we do in the following code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left= 7.5em, right= 7.5em, bottom=13em]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
   urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
   linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
   citecolor    = red   %Colour of citations
}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter
  \def\@pnumwidth{2em}
  \def\@tocrmarg {3.5em} % Also advisable
\makeatother

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{333}

\chapter{Quality of Service Optimization in Self-adapti\-ve}

Blah blah.

\chapter{Quality of Service Optimization in Self-adapti}

Foo bar.

\section{I should be sleeping now\ldots}
\ldots and not trying to post silly answer to \TeX.SX when I~am evidently too 
tired to reason correctly!


\section{I'll go}
Good night to everybody.

\section[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci elit enim ut fugiat]
Some text.

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Second (and easier) patch]

However, one might object that, in order to make more room for the page number, this solution causes the leaders (the “dots”) to stop earlier across the line.  This shouldn’t be a problem, but if it is, yet another remedy is feasible, which is illustrated below.  Note that, in this case, it is the `\@dottedtocline` command that needs to be patched (as well), since leaders occur only in entries for sections and lower level headings, which are produced via this command.  Note also that, in order to show that the patch actually works, the dots has been made closer to one another in this example.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left= 7.5em, right= 7.5em, bottom=13em]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
   urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
   linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
   citecolor    = red   %Colour of citations
}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hskip .5em \@plus 1fil % <<< MODIFICATION <<<
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hskip .5em \@plus 1fil % <<< MODIFICATION <<<
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
  \def\@dotsep{1.5} % <<< REMOVE THIS LINE! (It's included only to make the 
                    % result visible.)

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{333}

\chapter{Quality of Service Optimization in Self-adapti\-ve}

Blah blah.

\chapter{Quality of Service Optimization in Self-adapti}

Foo bar.

\section{I should be sleeping now\ldots}
\ldots and not trying to post silly answer to \TeX.SX when I~am evidently too 
tired to reason correctly!


\section{I'll go}
Good night to everybody.

\section[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci it]
Some text.

\end{document}
```

The output from this last example:
[image: Third (refined) patch]

It should be stressed that the first and the last patch *cannot be blindly applied* to document classes other than *book*, or when particular packages are being used; the second one, on the other hand, has better chances to work under more general circumstances.

Finally, I think it is worth mentioning that the issue we are talking about is *not* addressed by the *fixltx2e* package.

Comment: I added these line to the document, but the effect seems to be different in my case. The end of "Network" does move a bit to the left, but at the same time the dotted line gets shortened and the effect remains the same. I will post a screenshot of the new toc.

Comment: @claudia: It seems to me that your second screen shot shows that the situation has improved somehow.  Try making `\@pnumwidth` higher, _e.g._, `2.5em`.

Comment: yes, I have tried that, but the effect is to just shorten the dotted line, and some long titles are still sticking out. I just realized, however, I am the cause of my own trouble: In the beginning I was trying to solve another problem, where the 4 digits section numbers (eg. 10.10) were touching the beginning of the title. To solve that, I am using the package tocstyle, which solved the first problem, but created the second.
They do say that the current version of tocstyle is not fully reliable, so maybe if I find a different solution for my first problem, I can avoid creating the second!

Comment: I will post more screenshots above.

Comment: Just one more thing I wanted to point out. As you can see from my second screen shot above, the problem is not the fact that the dots are stopping earlier, they are in line with the other titles. The problem is still "Networks" that is sticking out.

Comment: OK, now the problem, and its cause, are clearer: but setting `\@pnumwidth` to, say, `2.5em` should fix it in spite of the `tocindentauto` option of the _tocstyle_ package (which is the option implied by default if you load the package without options, as you do).  I have tried to compile an example derived from the code you posted, and the `\@pnumwidth` fix works just fine for me, both for chapter toc entries (no leaders) and for section entries (with leaders), in all possible combinations of length.

Comment: @claudia: Anyway, a quick hand-crafted solution to your problem with the wider section number (10.10), without having recourse to the _tocstyle_ package, could be to redefine the `\l@section` command, more or less like this: `\renewcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.8em}}`.  This, *provided* that you don't have subsections, subsubsections, … listed in your toc (oherwise, you'll have to redefine `\l@subsection`, `\l@subsubsection`, … as well).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti, does the `\def\@tocrmarg {3.5em}` only apply to the sections and lower levels? Because when I modify that, it doesn't have an effect on the chapter titles.

Answer (score 1):

I have failed to reproduce the problem you are reporting. After corrections, I could compile with no further change and the output looked ok:

[image: Correct output]

I am only guessing here but I think you might be facing a problem of hyphenation. In fact, I was able to get and output similar to yours placing the word 'Networks' into an `\mbox{}`. Try writing the chapter name like:

```
\chapter{Quality of Service Optimization in Self-adaptive Sensor Net\-works}
```

so you help latex make the breaking correctly. Hope that helps!

Comment: I think that if it were a problem of hyphenation, the page number should appear shifted to the right, not partially overlapped, as it looks like in the posted image.  An `Overfull \hbox` would also be reported, of course (@claudia should check this out).

Comment: @jasikevicious: Of course we are not reproducing the problem, as long as the page number is 2!  With a three-digit page number the problem shows up!  Done a `showlists`, indeed appropriate glue is missing between the toc entry and its page number.  I guess expert advice is needed, here -- I'm speaking for myself, of course. ;-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti and @jasikevicius, the problem isn't due to hyphenation, I have tried to modify the header to Net\-work and it didn't produce any effect. It also doesn't report an `Overfull \hbox` in this point, but it does on other toc entries, which seem to be splitted just fine!

Comment: I used `\setcounter` as you mentioned @GustavoMezzetti so the page number has three digits now and still I could not reproduce her problem: latex goes for the hyphenation just fine. Again writing `\mbox{Networks}` does avoid the hyphenation and the problem appears. Anyway @claudia said that didn't work for her so I have run out of ideas...

Comment: @jasikevicius23, have you tried using the package tocstyle and having a section number with 3 digits?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti, does the `\def\@tocrmarg {3.5em}` only apply to the sections and lower levels? Because when I modify that, it doesn't have an effect on the chapter titles.

Comment: @anna: The `\@tocrmarg` parameter affects only “ToC lines” that are produced via the `\@dottedtocline` internal command.  In many document classes, “ToC lines” for chapter are produced without invoking “\@dottedtocline”, so are unaffected by changes in `\@tocrmarg`.  I think that Gonzalo Medina has already told you this.