# Length of Text in the Table of Contents page before the line numbers

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to control the length of text before the line numbers in the table of contents page.
I have attached a file to show the length of text. The link of my document is:

https://www.overleaf.com/project/6531bd5d181592ed690d9384

[image: length of content string]
Somebody, please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: it would be better to post your code here itself in a compilable form - overleaf may not be available to some -- also see this -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244570/long-title-in-table-of-content-doesnt-break-properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what other packages you might have loaded, or if your code has already changed how the ToC is prepared, because no one else can read your project... but have you tried

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{80pt}
\makeatother
```